# Multipotentialite vs Polymath

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Why do we have these two words that seem like they describe the same thing; or are they different?

The word **polymath** has the definitions:

1. Someone who knows a lot about many different things [[Merriam-Webster Thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/polymath)]
2. A person of encyclopedic learning. [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath)]

The word **multipotentialite** or someone having the trait of multipotentiality has the following definitions:

1. A multipotentialite is someone with many interests and creative pursuits. [[Puttylike](https://puttylike.com/terminology/)]
2. Someone with the ability and preference of a person, particularly one of strong intellectual or artistic curiosity, to excel in two or more different fields. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipotentiality#cite_note-Fisher-1)]

There are other similar words, but I would like to get a clear definition and distinction between these two words. The similarities between them seem to stem from the attribute of having a diverse interests and conveys an esteemed level of competency and a love for learning. The differences between the two words seems to convey that *multipotentiality* has a creative twist to it, whereas *polymath* seems to be based on deep knowledge and understanding.
Are these words the same? If not, what is it that distinguishes them?

Are these words the same? If not, what is it that distinguishes them?

Comment: Seems to me “polymath” is about knowing things, while a “multipotentialite” is about doing things.

Comment: You do realize,  I hope, that most people know neither of these two terms.

Comment: @tchrist does that make these words lesser? I'm here for curiosity not practicality.

Comment: @Jim I like that

Comment: @tchrist I feel that I've known _polymath_ for ever (obviously I haven't but it has been a long time since I learned it) but _multipotentialite_ is a new one on me. Nice word, and l tend to agree with jim because I can see that someone who is an excellent woodworker, stonemason, potter, blacksmith and dressmaker would be a multipotentialite but not a polymath.

Comment: Polymath is a good deal more common (Google Ngrams isn't giving me any results for multipotentialite, and multipotentialite doesn't seem to be in most dictionaries).

Comment: Obviously one word specifically concerns knowledge, while the other concerns potentialities (of whatever kind). Why would anybody think that they mean the same? While tchrist's comment may have sounded dismissive, it is, in fact, highly relevant: words do not get their meanings from Wikipedia definitions, but through actual use, so it is difficult to say much about the meaning of a word that is used very little, like *multipotentialite*, apart from what follows from its etymology.

Comment: @StuartF Doesn't make it not a word; "if words just meant words then they would be meaningless" - Bertrand Russel

Comment: Also why do people down-vote this. It is a genuine question and I don't understand why this community rejects the exploration into the meaning of words like this. Even if this comment section has convinced me that this word is not established enough to have a concrete answer. THAT IS an answer and an interesting interrogation into words -> So why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

> The terms "multipotentialite" and "polymath" are not identical even
> though they are often used interchangeably. You need not be an expert
> or a master in several fields to be a multipotentialite.
> Multipotentialite simply means a person with potential in multiple
> fields owing to his/her diverse interests and creative pursuits in
> life. Polymaths, on the other hand, are distinguished by their mastery
> and expertise in several fields. In this sense, multipotentialites can
> be viewed as potential polymaths.

I hope this helps. To learn more, visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipotentiality.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have these two words that seem like they describe the same thing?

We do not. In English, if the word or phrase is different, then the meaning, or at least the nuance, is different.

There are very, very few true synonyms in English.

The definitions for the examples you give are clearly distinct.